# What are the Ikarus C42 wing loading limits?

Tags: general-aviation, ikarus-c42

I have been reading about the Ikarus C42 aircraft as a potential personal recreation aircraft.  It compares very favorably with the Cessna 152, most notably in weight, stall speed, and fuel economy.

Does anyone have info on the negative and positive G loading limits for this aircraft? Can it be dis-assembled for transportation and storage? Thanks.

Comment: Yes, I am interested in this "Volks Flugzeug".  Need to know how strong it is.  Not that I am planning aerobatics, like its lower landing speed.  Also curious about a bipe version.  Thanks!.

Answer (score 1):

My club has a C42B that is used both as a trainer and a recreational aircraft, so I stopped by and looked in the Pilot's Operating Handbook for that one.

Now, before I say anything else: obviously, if the exact values matter, then always consult the POH for the specific airframe in question!

With the above preliminaries thus out of the way:

- The structural limits are stated as maximum positive wing loading +4 G, and maximum negative wing loading -2 G.
- The wings can be removed, and the POH lays out the procedure for this (as well as, obviously, that for reattaching them).

At least while quickly glancing through the text, I didn't spot anything obvious which would indicate that this differs between variants in the C42 series.

Comment: Thanks, appreciate the info.

Comment: @RobertDiGiovanni I notice you haven't upvoted or accepted. Are you looking for more in an answer?

Comment: No, looks very strong.  Thanks.